# SQL Developer 4.0 won't start on Mac OS Lion (Stock on Loading Screen)

Tags: java, java-7, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been looking for a solution to this problem because I want to use this software in my mac but seems not to work any of the solutions I found..

1. of course installing the latest version of JAVA -> JDK 7
2. changing sqldeveloper-Darwin.conf and SetJavaHome /Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
3. same but changed to /Home/bin just to try diff solutions to the problem
4. I also changed the sqldeveloper.conf and put the SetJavaHome /Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home there
5. try to run the sqldeveloper (/Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin) shell waiting to see if was going to prompt me or ask me for JDK or whatever a set it to /usr (but never happened)
6. going crazy now, so decide to make the post to see if someone can help or figure which step I am missing and maybe not seen the mistake..

This is where the program hangs...

```
at 
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.internalStart(EquinoxLauncher.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.start(EquinoxLauncher.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:258)
    at org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso.start(Netigso.java:190)
    at org.netbeans.NetigsoHandle.startFramework(NetigsoHandle.java:198)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1189)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1011)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:340)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:301)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:181)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:150)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:307)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I really hope, someone can help me, I really tired of booting on Windows to run SQL Developer plus I find it kinda dumb that Oracle don't encounter this kind of issue to make users experience more nice.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is one solution. I have been using SQL Developer for some time now, and i am not happy about it (I am on a MAC btw), there are so many bugs and the intellisense sucks. It is a functional program nevertheless.

Download and use navicat instead. Or try to find another one instead. It might not be the solution you are looking for, but i will recommend it.
http://www.navicat.com